# Unable to get through Postgres connection with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

For sake of Lord, I'm unable to understand why postgres is complaining about password authentication(using ActiveRecord).

```
sudo -u postgres psql rdb
```

This work (no password is asked)

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

But when connecting with an ORM like ActiveRecord it complains.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'postgresql', username: 'postgres', database: 'rdb')
```

---

```
 The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

This a basic setup and I was expecting this to work all the time. My last resort would be to allow `trust` or `md5`(on pg_hba.conf) but before I move ahead with that can some please provide me with some pointer as to why the above did not work.

Just an update postgres is running at `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo` command is triggering the `local all postgres peer` restriction, not asking for a password. The ActiveRecord configuration with the `postgresql` adapter uses this:

> :host - Defaults to a Unix-domain socket in /tmp. On machines without
>   Unix-domain sockets, the default is to connect to localhost.

Do you have working sockets on your machine? Is `/tmp` writeable? It might be the case that a TCP connection to `127.0.0.1` is used, triggering the password check as indicated by `md5`.

Comment: I have a unix socket located in `/var/run/postgresql/` with `.s.PGSQL.5432         .s.PGSQL.5432.lock`